# Objects disappearing from the hierarchy on new scene Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, hierarchy, scene

I am developing a game with Unity Collab in the last months, but always on one scene. Now that I want to create a new scene some things happen:

1. lighting settings are not shared (it is not a big deal because I can do them again)
2. every object that I add or copy from the other scene is appearing, but if I change the scene and go back here again there is nothing. My friends on collab actually see objects in it, and also the lights like the other scene but mine is always empty

What should I do?

[image]

Always empty like that

Comment: Use WinZip. Kidding.

Comment: Ate you saving? You dont mention that. Lighting is not shared between all your scenes. Are there any errors?

Comment: @BugFinder no errors and I am saving and also publishing